# Why doesn't a custom post type permalink ever hit index.php

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

So, I've got an entirely custom theme which has a number of custom post-types.

I've also got a custom taxonomy which I can visit on the front end with URLs such as:

```
www.mysite.local/custom-tax/custom-term
```

Which runs a query giving me results of posts that match the term 'custom-term' in the tax 'custom-tax'. Also paginates, etc.

When it comes to the custom post type pages, e.g. I've got a CPT of 'submissions' with the permalink slug set to 'your-reviews', the backend suggests the permalink will be:

```
www.mysite.local/your-reviews/my-new-awesome-post/
```

Which 404's.

I've checked out the WP template hierarchy and everything falls back to index.php which routes to the various custom templates that need to be used depending on the part of the site the user is visiting etc. So if I change the first line in **index.php** to a

```
die
```

or

```
wp_die
```

I'd expect no matter which page I visit, I'd always get the message in the die statement even for the 404'ing custom post type page.

It's worth noting that I get a 404 whether I visit the 'archive' page at:

```
www.mysite.local/your-reviews/
```

Or the individual page (some of which are 'hierarchical' and produce a permalink such as (the non-hierarchical pages also 404).

```
www.mysite.local/your-reviews/my-parent/my-new-awesome-post/
```

**Updated**

So, the code that generates this specific CPT (alongside a few others) is:

```
define( 'LL_POSTTYPE_ONELINER', 'll_submissions' );

$args = array(
    'label' => __('Submissions'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', // ?
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/thumb_up.png',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "submissions" ),
    'supports'=> array('title', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ) ,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array()

);

register_post_type( LL_POSTTYPE_ONELINER, $args);
```

Note, whilst this one's marked as 'hierarchical' => 'true', others that aren't hierarchical also 404 in the same way.

And to follow up, from the reply I've had so far, out of the template hierarchy (single.php, etc...) I only have `index.php` which it never hits.

Comment: If you are asking how to fix your CPT permalink issue, I recommend including the code used to create the CPT.

Comment: You say the URL will be 'your-reviews' but the registration code says the slug is actually:  'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "submissions" ),

Comment: Try www.mysite.local/submissions/my-new-awesome-post/

Comment: I tried changing the code in case WP didn't like `/your-reviews/` to `submissions` (and flushed permalinks) and it's made no difference unforuntately.

Answer (score 1):

Your Custom Post Type is using the single.php and (most likely) archive.php templates.

[A single CPT post looks for templates in this order](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display):

- single-{post_type}.php - If the post type were product, WordPress would look for single-product.php
- single.php
- index.php

[Other CPT pages look for templates in this order](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display):

- taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{slug}.php
- taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php - If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress would look for taxonomy-* sometax.php
- taxonomy.php
- archive.php
- index.php

Comment: So, assuming my theme doesn't have any of the above  except for the `index.php` (it doesn't) then it should hit `index.php`, and then trip the die statement? This is kinda my problem...

Comment: Are the only files in your theme index.php and a functions.php?  If not, what files exist?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, got locked out of my G account, there's an index php, no single, no archive. Some how I've got single CPT pages working (yey) but the archive URL still never hit index.php-- I'm not even sure where to start debugging if I can't get to the die command in line one of index.php. Is there a script that routes into a template file that I can bob some debug code in?

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed your permalinks? Whenever you change a Custom post type or taxonomy you must flush permalinks else you'll get 404s

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, didn't help unfortunately :(